# Page not found (404) Request Method: POST Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/edit_post/post

Tags: django

I believe I have configure everything properly, but I can't seem to figure out what is causing the error message.

What I'm trying to do is applying a view that allows me to edit a blog post.

**Error message:**

```
Using the URLconf defined in diyblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
blog/ [name='index']
blog/ blogs/ [name='all-posts']
blog/ <int:post_id> [name='post-details']
blog/ new_post/ [name='new-post']
blog/ edit_post/<int:post_id> [name='edit-post']
summernote/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, blog/edit_post/post, didn’t match any of these.
```

**View:**

```
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)

    edit_form = PostForm(instance=post)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit_form.is_valid():
            mod_post = edit_form.save(commit=False)
            mod_post.save()
            return redirect(get_all_posts)

    context_dict = {
        'edit_form': edit_form
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/edit_post.html', context=context_dict)
```

**Form:**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body',)
        exclude = ['author', ]

        widgets = {
            'body': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
```

**url patterns:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('blogs/', views.get_all_posts, name='all-posts'),
    path('<int:post_id>', views.get_post_details, name='post-details'),
    path('new_post/', views.add_new_post, name='new-post'),
    path('edit_post/<int:post_id>', views.edit_post, name='edit-post')
]
```

**Template:**

```
<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<form action="post" method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ edit_form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Save changes</button>
    <form>
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I'm receiving this error message and why it's happening?

Comment: Try removing action attribute from the form (make it just <form method='post'>)

Comment: @YuriSh It doesn't work, although the error message doesn't appear anymore.

Comment: I think you need to populate PostForm object, passing the request form as the first argument.

`edit_form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)`

Comment: If it fixes the problem I will post a more detailed answer

Comment: @YuriSh it works, however when I click "Edit Post" it used to show the fields content as they were before (which is what I intended). For example, if I have a long post, but only want to edit a certain part, I can see the old post content and edit on top of it.

But now, when I click Edit the fields appear empty and it looks as if I'm just creating a new post.

Does it make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, I forgot to mention that line shouldn't go in place of the existing one but rather should be added to the conditional block, just after `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: @YuriSh it works perfectly! Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the action attribute of the form tag isn't supposed to be there. What it does is specify the url to which the form request will be made, relative to the current document url. In this case it replaced the last part of the url (integer id of the edited post) to plainly '/post', thus throwing 404 as your server didn't expect requests to that path.

(The POST request was being sent to /blog/edit_post/post, whereas if you remove the action attribute, it will be sent to the same address you see in the browser nav bar when you're on that page)

Secondly, your edit_post handler completely ignored the request payload, instead it found the persisted post and saved it again.
[Relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

The last problem with the form being empty upon being loaded is a bit trickier to explain if you don't know what's going on already. Both requests to display the page and to save the changes are located under the same url and share the same handler (`edit_post`). Accordingly, the conditional clause checks if the current request method is GET (assumed by default) or POST, and depending on that follows different branches.

Answer (score 0):

**'post'** isn't an integer `path('edit_post/<int:post_id>', views.edit_post, name='edit-post')`

if you want the URL to be a string, use **slug**: `path('edit_post/<slug:post_id>', views.edit_post, name='edit-post')`